# check date in laravel for an output

Tags: mysql, date, laravel-5, output

It seems to be a bit different in Laravel as in CodeIgniter if you want to check a date.

My variable *anniversary* has the type *date* in my database. In the most columns I still have *0000-00-00*.

In case a date has *0000-00-00* I want that it will doesn't shown. How can I check this?

At the output of *0000-00-00* I get the following result *-0001-11-30 00:00:00* and don't understand it.

Comment: post your model code

Comment: You want to query so that you do not have the column that contains '0000-00-00' or you want to convert the rows after fetching the data?

Comment: I want to convert the data for a check. In case the date is _2016-02-10_ then i want to show it but it is still _0000-00-00_ then i don't want to show it.

Comment: @bkf why do you want my model at a normally easy if query? I only don't know how I can make it in laravel compared to codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP `DateTime` to convert your dates. [Reference here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
$anniversary = new DateTime('2016-02-10');
$anniversary->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //Whatever format you wish to get
```

For a full reference about the format, you can look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).